# Get free account role instead of user account role Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I'm having a trouble getting this account role free because in some tutorials the role they have are FREE and not USER . I'm trying to test my app on my real device but I couldn't build it . So can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have "FREE", what you have is fine.
Usually to sideload (install on the device) the easiest way is to enable the "automatically manage signing" in the Project File (Project Navigator `command+1`), the top element.
On the left you'll find your target, there you must put a bundle identifier (usually a reverse url like com.myorganization.myapp). 
Enable the automatic signing and you should be able to install on your phone.